# How to detect and exploit an SQLi in a POST method

Tags: sql-injection

Making it simple (no security at all), when we want to detect whether or not a GET parameter is vulnerable to SQLi, we could just type a ' as the value (?id=') and check if there is any error. (No blind SQL)

But in the case that the parameter is sent using a POST method, how can I detect if it is vulnerable? And then how to exploit it? I think that using a proxy and intercept the query will be the solution, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to do both (detect & exploit) is to download sqlmap and use the -r option.

Capture the POST request using any proxy tool, paste it into a file, then do:

```
# sqlmap -r <text_file_with_raw_POST_request>
```

(add --force-ssl switch if needed)

From: https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a proxy or a tool like Firebug to modify POST parameters before sending them. Personally I prefer to use a proxy like ZAP or Burp as they have some nice tools which allow you to automate the attack and load lists of payloads to test.